# Notepad++ - Is it possible to use custom fonts?

Tags: php, fonts, notepad++

Since I use different languages (Latin and non-Latin ones) in my work and some of them (for example Cyrillic languages) have symbols that look exactly the same as Latin ones, sometimes I get those stupid mistakes which are extremely hard to find when I accidentally use Cyrillic symbol in my code instead of the Latin one.

For example, the following variable names (PHP-style) look exactly the same, although half of the characters in the second name are Cyrillic symbols (and thus have different codes):

```
 $iicuxiphametod vs $іiсuхiрhаmеtоd
```

So I've come up with idea of using for style configuration those fonts whose Latin and Cyrillic symbols have different appearance. I've found several fonts of that type - SimSun-ExtB, NSimSun, MingLiU-ExtB etc. - but the problem is that I'd like to use a font that I've created myself.

Does anybody know which fonts are used in the Notepad++? Are they it's own fonts or system fonts and is it possible to use different (non-system, user-created) font in Notepad++ (Settings->Style Configurator->Font Style) or just to edit existing one?

Comment: the list of font names you see in Style Configurator are system fonts (fonts that are installed to your OS). Why don't you install your user-created font to your OS?

Comment: When I check my font-lists under the Style-Configurator I get all of everything on my computer.  Have you tried installing new fonts to test it, yet?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No, I haven't tried it yet. I have to create my font first. I was just checking if that's possible.

Comment: since this particular question is already answered it would be nice if you could choose an answer as solution. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings -> Style Configurator...

select: Global Styles and Default Style

at Font Style you can then select the default font wich is (in windows) in the systems font directory.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've touched my Windows machine and with it Notepad++ but, from what memory I have of that time, when using notepad++ you should be able to change the font under settings/preferences somewhere, and so long as your font is a valid font-set ie TTF or other supported format, all you have to do or should have to do is have it installed in your Windows font directory, and then in those settings/prefs choose that font you created.

Comment: I'd kill for a version of TextWrangler on Windows